# Imported product not visible in admin & database

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

I have imported data with csv file :

```
"_type",sku,"_attribute_set",websites,store,qty,tax_class_id,visibility,name,price,description,short_description,weight,status,pro_position,casa_position,show_on_homepage,main_product,bottle_litres,category_ids,is_in_stock
"simple","1234","Default","base","es",12,4,1,"Bebidas refrescantes",75,"Lo  amarás","Lo amarás",2.8,1,34,38,"Yes","No",3.86,10,"In Stock"
```

I am getting success message as :

```
Import successfully done.
```

Still data is not present in database too.What is wrong?

Comment: try magmi........

Answer (score 1):

I'd say either your import file is corrupt (wrong line endings? should be linux style) or it is imported but doesn't show up (yet). Have you checked the main product table?

`SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku = '1234';`

If you get an entry, the product has been imported.